# cannot find symbol in the class LegacyAudioDeviceModule error in import org.webrtc.audio.LegacyAudioDeviceModule;

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have just imported the project and during gradle build it says the following error :

```
error: cannot find symbol
import org.webrtc.audio.LegacyAudioDeviceModule;
                       ^
  symbol:   class LegacyAudioDeviceModule
```

i have seen the files:

[image: available in image]

i am unable to see LegacyAudioDeviceModule in the picture. I think this missing file is causing error in my app. how can i fix this error? i am android studio beginner and don't know much about it.

```
    AudioDeviceModule createLegacyAudioDevice() {
        // Enable/disable OpenSL ES playback.
        if (!peerConnectionParameters.useOpenSLES) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Disable OpenSL ES audio even if device supports it");
            WebRtcAudioManager.setBlacklistDeviceForOpenSLESUsage(true /* enable */);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Allow OpenSL ES audio if device supports it");
            WebRtcAudioManager.setBlacklistDeviceForOpenSLESUsage(false);
        }

        if (peerConnectionParameters.disableBuiltInAEC) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Disable built-in AEC even if device supports it");
            WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedAcousticEchoCanceler(true);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Enable built-in AEC if device supports it");
            WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedAcousticEchoCanceler(false);
        }

        if (peerConnectionParameters.disableBuiltInNS) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Disable built-in NS even if device supports it");
            WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedNoiseSuppressor(true);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Enable built-in NS if device supports it");
            WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedNoiseSuppressor(false);
        }

        WebRtcAudioTrack.setErrorCallback(new WebRtcAudioTrack.ErrorCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onWebRtcAudioTrackInitError(String errorMessage) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onWebRtcAudioTrackInitError: " + errorMessage);
                reportError(errorMessage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onWebRtcAudioTrackStartError(
                    WebRtcAudioTrack.AudioTrackStartErrorCode errorCode, String errorMessage) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onWebRtcAudioTrackStartError: " + errorCode + ". " + errorMessage);
                reportError(errorMessage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onWebRtcAudioTrackError(String errorMessage) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onWebRtcAudioTrackError: " + errorMessage);
                reportError(errorMessage);
            }
        });

        return new LegacyAudioDeviceModule();
    }

    AudioDeviceModule createJavaAudioDevice() {
        // Enable/disable OpenSL ES playback.
        if (!peerConnectionParameters.useOpenSLES) {
            Log.w(TAG, "External OpenSLES ADM not implemented yet.");
            // TODO(magjed): Add support for external OpenSLES ADM.
        }

        JavaAudioDeviceModule.AudioTrackErrorCallback audioTrackErrorCallback = new JavaAudioDeviceModule.AudioTrackErrorCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onWebRtcAudioTrackInitError(String errorMessage) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onWebRtcAudioTrackInitError: " + errorMessage);
                reportError(errorMessage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onWebRtcAudioTrackStartError(
                    JavaAudioDeviceModule.AudioTrackStartErrorCode errorCode, String errorMessage) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onWebRtcAudioTrackStartError: " + errorCode + ". " + errorMessage);
                reportError(errorMessage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onWebRtcAudioTrackError(String errorMessage) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onWebRtcAudioTrackError: " + errorMessage);
                reportError(errorMessage);
            }
        };
        Log.v(TAG, "disableBuiltInAEC="+!peerConnectionParameters.disableBuiltInAEC);
        Log.v(TAG, "disableBuiltInNS="+!peerConnectionParameters.disableBuiltInNS);
        return JavaAudioDeviceModule.builder(appContext)
                .setUseHardwareAcousticEchoCanceler(!peerConnectionParameters.disableBuiltInAEC)
                .setUseHardwareNoiseSuppressor(!peerConnectionParameters.disableBuiltInNS)
                .setAudioTrackErrorCallback(audioTrackErrorCallback)
                .createAudioDeviceModule();
    }

    private void createMediaConstraintsInternal() {
        // Create video constraints if video call is enabled.
        if (isVideoCallEnabled()) {
            videoWidth = peerConnectionParameters.videoWidth;
            videoHeight = peerConnectionParameters.videoHeight;
            videoFps = peerConnectionParameters.videoFps;

            // If video resolution is not specified, default to HD.
            if (videoWidth == 0 || videoHeight == 0) {
                videoWidth = HD_VIDEO_WIDTH;
                videoHeight = HD_VIDEO_HEIGHT;
            }

            // If fps is not specified, default to 30.
            if (videoFps == 0) {
                videoFps = 30;
            }
            Logging.d(TAG, "Capturing format: " + videoWidth + "x" + videoHeight + "@" + videoFps);
        }

        // Create audio constraints.
        audioConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
        // added for audio performance measurements
        if (peerConnectionParameters.noAudioProcessing) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Disabling audio processing");
            audioConstraints.mandatory.add(
                    new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair(AUDIO_ECHO_CANCELLATION_CONSTRAINT, "false"));
            audioConstraints.mandatory.add(
                    new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair(AUDIO_AUTO_GAIN_CONTROL_CONSTRAINT, "false"));
            audioConstraints.mandatory.add(
                    new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair(AUDIO_HIGH_PASS_FILTER_CONSTRAINT, "false"));
            audioConstraints.mandatory.add(
                    new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair(AUDIO_NOISE_SUPPRESSION_CONSTRAINT, "false"));
        }
        // Create SDP constraints.
        sdpMediaConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
        sdpMediaConstraints.mandatory.add(
                new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveAudio", "true"));
        sdpMediaConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair(
                "OfferToReceiveVideo", Boolean.toString(isVideoCallEnabled())));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you importing LegacyAudioDeviceModule. Apparently it was removed, it seems now you need to use JavaAudioDeviceModule

```
import org.webrtc.audio.JavaAudioDeviceModule;
```

Comment: so can i use LegacyAudioDeviceModule with some older version of the dependency , can you please help me solve this error

Comment: In the new version, this class has been removed since it is deprecated. Why aren't you using the JavaAudioDeviceModule from the same package?

Comment: I dont know how to change my existing code from LegacyDeviceAudioModule to JavaAudioDeviceModule . could you please edit my code and do some correction in it and replace it . i will paste the code in question

Comment: I did not work with this library, I can only advise either use a more old version or use a similar library or rewrite the code myself

Comment: can you please give me older version no. which has legacyAudioDeviceModule in it . please help . it is important . i have also posted the code , just have a look if you know hot to correct it

Comment: Thank you bro , changing the dependency to lower version worked . thanks a lot .

Comment: Nevertheless, this is a bad approach, since you are using an outdated version, it would be better if you figured out and implemented everything on the new version

Answer (score 1):

i changed the dependency to version implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.24064' and it worked , previously i was using latest dependency but when i moved to this version . it worked .